# Issues with flex-box

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-position

So I have a question about flexbox. Basically, I'm creating a card component. I'd like the image on the left and the card body on the right. I have it.. Sort of.

The problem is the card is bigger than the image. I'd like the card to stay the height of the image.

Here is my code:

```css
.card-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-horizontal__image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

.card-horizonal__body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='st-grid-12'>
  <div class='card-horizontal'>
    <div class='card-horizontal__imgage'>
      <img alt='' src='https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400'>
    </div>
    <div class='card-horizonal__body'>
      <h2>This is a title</h2>
      <p class='card__copy'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis velit accusamus non numquam assumenda quaerat, consequatur recusandae facilis inventore dicta, distinctio magni obcaecati vel aliquid, fugit maxime. Voluptas, ullam officiis?</p>
      <div class='btn btn--secondary'>Read More</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, first you have a typo in the class name "`.card-horizontal__imgag`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you had a typo in your class, And second you had a misuse of your display: flex

Here is your css now

```
  .card-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  }

  .card-horizontal__imgage {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-position: center;  
    display: flex;  
  }

  .card-horizonal__body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: white;
    padding: 15px 20px;
  }
```

I'm sure you can tell why I did that border and commented the shadow. To show you they're truly equal in size.

here is the code working

```css
  .card-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .card-horizontal__imgage {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-position: center;  
    display: flex;  
  }

  .card-horizonal__body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: white;
  /*   box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23); */
    padding: 15px 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class='st-grid-12'>
  <div class='card-horizontal'>
    <div class='card-horizontal__imgage'>
      <img alt='' src='https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400'>
    </div>
    <div class='card-horizonal__body'>
      <h2>This is a title</h2>
      <p class='card__copy'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis velit accusamus non numquam assumenda quaerat, consequatur recusandae facilis inventore dicta, distinctio magni obcaecati vel aliquid, fugit maxime. Voluptas, ullam officiis?</p>
      <div class='btn btn--secondary'>Read More</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT

To ease the worries about the shadow, I added the shadow to the entire card, which is how it should be done anyway. You can't count the shadow as height. Shadows are CSS embellishments, like an outline for example. It doesn't add size to the item even if it appears that way....Checking the browser dev tool will answer some of these questions.

Comment: That does not work. You removed the `box-shadow` which is part of the design. When I uncomment the box-shadow nothing has changed from my original code.

Comment: The box shadow is not part of the height. If he wants to account for that, he'll have to take away the depth of the shadow from the container height, programmatically. In this case with JSX since he's running React. If you make an object, you can change the shadow as large as you want, it will not affect the size of the object

Comment: @ThomasBrushel Also, the shadow problem can be solved by adding the shadow to the entire card. check the codepen again

Comment: Thank you, Luis!! This helped a lot!

Comment: You said _Shadows are CSS embellishments, like a border for example. It doesn't add size..._, well, border does :) ... outline does not

Comment: @LGSon That's correct. But you got my point. However, I will update that for any beginner that may see it. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

First, as I mentioned in the comments, in your HTML, you have a typo on the `class='card-horizontal__imgage'` code.

The issue is that the height of the overall card is causing the image `div` to stretch to be taller than the image by 4 pixels. Setting a `height` on the card itself solves the problem.

You have `background-position: center;` in your CSS, but that does nothing if the element you apply it to doesn't have a background. Another way to solve the issue (and that's what I'm showing below) is to not use an image element at all and just set the image as the background-image for the `div` element that is supposed to hold it.

Also, applying the `box-shadow` to the entire card, instead of just the text area on the right, makes for a better looking result. Remember, the shadow is applied outside of the element's height.

```css
.card-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height:25%;  
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.card-horizontal__image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400");
  background-size:cover;
}

.card-horizonal__body{
  background: white;
  padding:15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='st-grid-12'>
        <div class='card-horizontal'>
          <div class='card-horizontal__image'></div>
          <div class='card-horizonal__body'>
            <h2>This is a title</h2>
            <p class='card__copy'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis velit accusamus non numquam assumenda quaerat, consequatur recusandae facilis inventore dicta, distinctio magni obcaecati vel aliquid, fugit maxime. Voluptas, ullam officiis?</p>
            <div class='btn btn--secondary'>Read More</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is your spelling problem. in css you write .card-horizontal__image but in your html code you write .card-horizontal__imgage . just correct this spelling than code running well

Answer (score 0):

When I look, the card is only slightly larger than the image.  This seems to be due to the extra space that images have below them by default, as they are display:inline;

To remove this small space, and make the image column the same height as your card, make the image element display:block;

```
.card-horizontal__imgage img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Then he's not using flexbox anymore.

Comment: He is still using flexbox for the layout, just making the image inside the flex child a block element.

Comment: Since when do images get extra space below them by default because they are inline elements? And, have you tried your solution? It makes no change to the layout at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was going to type the same thing!

Comment: @ThomasBrushel This is not a correct explanation nor does it solve the problem. See my answer below for a working solution.